# Plot a bubble chart using plotly

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly

I am working to plot some data in a Bubble Chart using plotly. I have written this code: (based on [Plotly's examples](https://plot.ly/python/bubble-charts/))

```
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=output['mean'],
    y=output['count'],
    text=output.index,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=['rgb(93, 164, 214)', 'rgb(255, 144, 14)',  'rgb(44, 160, 101)', 'rgb(255, 65, 54)'],
        size=output['total'],
    )
)

data = [trace0]
plot_url = py.plot_mpl(trace0, filename='mpl-7d-bubble')
```

I am trying to plot `output['mean']` on the x axis and `output['count']` on the y. I would like to plot the size on `output['total'].` When it is run, this error is received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..data.py", line 45, in <module>
    plot_url = py.plot_mpl(data, filename='mpl-7d-bubble')
  File "...anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py", line 307, in plot_mpl
    fig = tools.mpl_to_plotly(fig, resize=resize, strip_style=strip_style)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plotly/tools.py", line 507, in mpl_to_plotly
    matplotlylib.Exporter(renderer).run(fig)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plotly/matplotlylib/mplexporter/exporter.py", line 45, in run
    fig.savefig(io.BytesIO(), format='png', dpi=fig.dpi)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

**EDIT:** Contents of `output` pandas dataframe:

```
             count     location        mean        total
StartLocation                                             
?                  6            ?    9.527778    57.166667
bathroom          14     bathroom   20.409524   285.733333
bedroom           61      bedroom   96.837432  5907.083333
bedroom2          22     bedroom2  165.262121  3635.766667
hallway            6      hallway    0.394444     2.366667
kitchen           79      kitchen    8.646624   683.083333
living room       56  living room   93.855655  5255.916667
outside            6      outside  325.991667  1955.950000
setup              1        setup    0.050000     0.050000
study             18        study   18.099074   325.783333
toilet            51       toilet    7.198693   367.133333
```

Comment: please print output

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, print output of what?

Comment: The output variable you use in output ['mean']

Comment: @eyllanesc Have done so.

Comment: output variable is pandas dataframe?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah -  a large amount of preprocessing occurs so it makes the most sense.

Comment: Why do you use plot_url = py.plot_mpl (trace0, filename = 'mpl-7d-bubble')
 And no py.iplot (data, filename = 'bubblechart-size')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple of small issues preventing you from getting the plot.

- plotly expects `data` to be a `plotly.graph_objs.Data` object

  ```
  data = go.Data([trace0])
  ```
- Your size markers are too big, you need to minimize them to something reasonable

  ```
  size=[i / 100 for i in output['total']]
  ```

### [image: Plotly plot]

The complete code for the image above.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import io

txt = """room count location mean total
? 6 ? 9.527778 57.166667
bathroom 14 bathroom 20.409524 285.733333
bedroom 61 bedroom 96.837432 5907.083333
bedroom2 22 bedroom2 165.262121 3635.766667
hallway 6 hallway 0.394444 2.366667
kitchen 79 kitchen 8.646624 683.083333
livingroom 56 livingroom 93.855655 5255.916667
outside 6 outside 325.991667 1955.950000
setup 1 setup 0.050000 0.050000
study 18 study 18.099074 325.783333
toilet 51 toilet 7.198693 367.133333"""

t = io.StringIO(txt)
output = pd.read_csv(t, sep=' ')

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=output['mean'],
    y=output['count'],
    text=output.room,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color=['rgb(93, 164, 214)', 'rgb(255, 144, 14)',  'rgb(44, 160, 101)', 'rgb(255, 65, 54)'],
        size=[i / 100 for i in output['total']],
    )
)

data = go.Data([trace0])
plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='mpl-7d-bubble')
```